# Can incorporating static classes into a design improve performance?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am in a design patterns course right now, and my professor mentioned that there are some cases where using a static class with static functions to do all the calculations and then having separate object classes to store the data to be calculated on could be most efficient.  How practical is this approach?  I know there would be tight coupling between the static class and the objects, but would this actually give you a performance boost if the calculations are lengthy?

Comment: This depends on the implementation of each language and/or compiler. At best though you'll save a single pointer dereference. The benefits are negligible compared eg to using the parallelization and vectorization features found on almost all languages.

Comment: For example, in C# `someArray.AsParallel().Sum()` can run roughly 4 times faster than `someArray.Sum()` on a quad processor. Using the vectorization functions found eg in Vector4 to deal with 4 floats at a time can quadruple speed *per core*

Comment: I code mostly in Java and C#.  Is parallelization the same as multi-threading?  (I have never heard of parallelization or vectorization before)

Comment: Let the nature of your problem drive your design (domain driven design). Having these kind of considerations in most cases not only does not give performance advantage, it just prevents from having a good design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static function calls generally have less overhead because no object reference needs to be passed. If this causes a significant performance difference depends on your use case and on the environment. According to my experience, it is unlikely.

Still I am convinced that it is often a good thing to incorporate standalone functions or static functions into a design, not only for performance reasons. The whole functional programming paradigm relies on using functions rather than classes as building blocks. It helps to reduce mutable state, simplifies testing and at least theoretically supports automated parallelization.